# Why does python import a lower version of Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I installed numpy with pip, version 1.15

```
pip show numpy
python -m pip show numpy

Name: numpy
Version: 1.15.0
```

However when I import numpy with python, I get version 1.7.1

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.7.1'
```

Where is this numpy coming from and how can I disable it?

I checked on all folders from the sys.path, and erased folders of numpy version 1.7.1

> > > import sys
> > >       sys.path
> > >           ['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/hirsch/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']

But that did not solve this issue.

```
>>> which pip
/home/hirsch/.local/bin/pip

>>> which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Can you execute `which pip`?

Comment: added output to the post

Comment: Thanks. Your `pip` points to some local (user) installation of Python, while what you show comes from system version of Python. Can you run `which python`?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski also included now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `python -m pip` instead of `pip`, you likely have multiple pythons installed.

```
python -m pip show numpy

Name: numpy
Version: 1.7.1
```

`which pip` will tell you the path of your unwanted install

An other possible cause is that you have two Numpy's installed on the same python, in which case uninstall both and reinstall.

The thing is, if you have multiple versions of numpy and import it, python imports the first one it finds. You might want to look int virtual environment if you need to keep multiple versions of numpy (in every case, you have to uninstall older numpy's that are in conflict).

Comment: That is what I use, the output is 1.15.0

Comment: ` >>> python -m pip uninstall numpy
    Uninstalling numpy-1.15.0: `

Comment: then it proceeds with Uninstalling numpy-1.14.5 ... should I just keep removing all numpys? Why can't i just change the import path from where it is fetching the module?

Comment: it worked. I kept uninstalling until there was nothing left. Curiously no version was 1.7.1 so I can't explain that. Afterwards installed 1.15.0 it worked well. Can you edit your answer to explain that so I can accept it thanks!

Comment: So this is solved, but it seems you have another problem. You should check why `pip` and `python` don't point to the same python install. `~/.profile` is often a good place to start to check if there is something "suspycious". I don't really see what you want me to add to the answer, it looks complete to me now.